# PHP Laravel convert file doc to pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, ms-word

I want to convert a word file (.doc, .docx) to pdf. but I've done that using the library `PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings` doesn't match the style.

[image]

is there an easy library to use it?

Comment: Please try this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: that image above is result from phpoffice/phpword, success but without the style